# Why can't logos of companies be used by referring to nominative fair use?

Tags: trademark

Companies have trademarks on their logos. If I want to use their logos in my own production, I need permission to do so.

But if my production makes it clear that the use of the logo is only meant to *refer* to the company, wouldn't that fall under nominative fair use, and hence I don't need permission?

To make up an example on the spot, say I am in the smartphone market, and I want to create a commercial comparing my prices to that of my rivals, say Samsung and Apple.

Can I then in my commercial have an Apple logo and a Samsung logo along, and next to them list some average price for their phones?

Clearly then the use of the logo is there only to refer to Apple/Samsung and not to claim ownership over their logo in any way?

Comment: If you wanted to refer to the company, you would use its name, not its logo.

Comment: @Nij You might want both.

Answer (score 1):

A relevant case may be [New Kids on the Block v. News Am. Pub., Inc., 971 F.2d 302 (9th Cir. 1992)](https://cyber.harvard.edu/metaschool/fisher/domain/tmcases/newkids.htm), outlining a three-part test for nominative fair use:

> we hold that a commercial user is entitled to a nominative fair use defense provided he meets the following three requirements: First, the product or service in question must be one not readily identifiable without use of the trademark; **second, only so much of the mark or marks may be used as is reasonably necessary to identify the product or service**; [FN7] and third, the user must do nothing that would, in conjunction with the mark, suggest sponsorship or endorsement by the trademark holder.

The footnote says:

> Thus, a soft drink competitor would be entitled to compare its product to Coca-Cola or Coke, but would not be entitled to use Coca-Cola's distinctive lettering.

Comment: Yet PepsiCo _did_ use Coke's distinctive lettering (and trademark bottle shape) in its "Pepsi challenge" advertising campaigns.

Comment: I don't know. Could be Coke didn't sue because that would have looked bad; any such lawsuit would have been highly publicized. Could be the lawyers decided there was a good possibility that the use of the logo in that case *was* reasonably necessary (the footnote is, after all, dicta.)